# How to find File Explorer location?

Tags: android, system

I am using Eclipse. I can see the File Explorer in Eclipse. File Explorer contains lot of folders and files. In this files are stored to where in my computer. For example `data` and `mnt`. How to find their location in computer. Thanks.

Comment: What you see in DDMS is the file system of the Android device (or the virtual device). It does not _exist_ in _your computer_.

Comment: Read my previous comment again.

Comment: Thanks your information is useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand .
If you want your source code files then

> Right click on project -> Click on properties. Property "Location" has a
>   value field which will give your files

If you want to see sdcard.img, cache.img etc

> Goto AVD manager-> Find location of .android and go to your particular
>   emulator folder

data and mnt are in your virtual device- on your emulator, things saved on your sdcard are on the sdcard image above and not on your computer

if you want to pull files from mnt or such folders you can do this on the DOS cmd line

> adb pull /mnt/sdcard/filename.ext